# Trigger Different Informatica workflows run based on oracle table data

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Scenario: there are multiple source systems and individual workflows present for each of them. I shall query/read a file/table to check which source system is mentioned there and based on that specific workflow will run.

Source   WFname
s1        w1
s2        w2
s3        w3

In the file/table if I have find s1 and s3 then w1 and w3 should fire. 
I have windows system,If you are suggesting batch script please send me sample as  I am not expert in batch script.

Answer (score 0):

I created one for UNIX so dont have exact script for Windows. Steps i followed -

1. Split workflows in groups based on dependency - name them group 1,2,3... put the list in a table.
2. pickup group 1 and loop...

   2.1. pick first workflow, use 'pmcmd startworkflow' to start it. Pick next start it. do this until all in the group 1 exhausts. Log status as 'Running' in a table.

   2.2. create infinite loop - run pmcmd getworkflowdetails to check status of workflows in group 1 one by one. if all succeeds just exit this loop. else keep polling. Log status in a table.Log status as 'Succeeded' in a table. If any flow fails, log status 'Failed' and exit the shell. Checking status can be tricky - you need to store the output and look for '[Succeeded]' word.
3. pickup group 2 and repeat from step #2