# How to trigger an Informatica workflow from a windows batch file (.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file, informatica-powercenter

Can anyone plz let me know wat is the possible way to trigger an informatica workflow from a windows batch file (.bat)
Specifically the code/script for the same.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output / tracebacks). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can refer to this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60502640/trigger-different-informatica-workflows-run-based-on-oracle-table-data]